# php form - need to upload an image

Tags: php, mysql, image

Trying to make a simple script to comment on a news articles, it's working for the text but I would like the user to be able to submit a image to use as a icon or avatar. This is the form field:

```
<label>Add your avatar<span>*</span></label>
<input name="image" type="file"/>
```

and the form is directing to this script:

```
    <?php
    $formats = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ( $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 90000 && in_array($extension, $formats) ) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            // something went wrong, display the error using; $_FILES["file"]["error"];
        } else {
            if ( !file_exists("avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] ) ) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            }
        }
    }
    $tempLink = "http://www.website.com/avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $page_path = $_POST['page_path'];
    $con=mysqli_connect
    ("","","","");
     // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
     $sql="INSERT INTO comments (name, comment, email, storyid, entry_date)
     VALUES
     ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[comment]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[storyid]',now())";
     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
       {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
       }
    header('Location: http://www.website.com/' . $page_path);
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

The script runs to completiong but the image doesn't get saved to:

www.website.com/avatars/

all the other form data inserts into sql just fine. Only problem is the image. The targeted directory is chmode 0777.

Comment: The code that you've posted isn't making any attempt to process the image input. You say that you've tried things that don't work. Show what you've tried and indicate what the error is.

Comment: Have you looked in the PHP documentation on how to handle uploads, as I see no attempt to even deal with the uploaded file here?  You also have a number of other problems - SQL injection vulnerability; the fact that you don't validate any data whatsoever before adding the record to the DB; for example, you don't verify the file is uploaded, is of the proper type, and is successfully moved to new directory, before inserting to DB, etc.

Comment: Havent you heard of little Bobby Tables? http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it aint that hard. You can store the image as avatar using the following code:

```
$formats = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ( $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000 && in_array($extension, $formats) ) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] != 0) {
        // something went wrong, display the error using; $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    } else {
        if ( !file_exists("avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] ) ) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to do, is insert it into your sql by sending the sql query as a request when the image is moved or already exsist... can be done like this;

```
$tempLink = "http://example.com/avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Make sure you add it after the if-statement of file_exists. :)

Comment: the file isn't saving to the server. the folder is writable. the image I tested with is suitable size and extension. no error messages popping up, script runs. Other form data posts no problem

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it. I'll post the entire script I'm using. I've checked the save to folder and it's chmode 0777. I'm at a loss here

Comment: I needed to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form